# RESTful URLs with Jersey 2 subresources?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

Is there a way to use Resorces both as root and as sub-resource?
I want to call my api endpoint this way:

```
GET /persons/{id}/cars      # get all cars for a person
GET /cars                   # get all cars
```

How to implement my resources to use this url schema?

Person resource:

```
@Path("persons")
public class PersonsResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}/cars")
    public CarsResource getPersonCars(@PathParam("id") long personId) {
        return new CarsResource(personId);
    }
}
```

Cars resource:

```
@Path("cars")
public class CarsResource {

    private Person person;

    public CarsResource(long personId) {
        this.person = findPersonById(personId);
    }

    @GET
    public List<Car> getAllCars() {
        // ...
    }

    @GET
    public List<Cars> getPersonCars() {
        return this.person.getCars();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it that way, instead you inject an instance of `CarsResource` into `PersonsResource', and then you call the method of`getPersonCars`, as follows

```
@Path("persons")
public class PersonsResource {

  @inject
  private CarsResource carsResource;

  @GET
  @Path("{id}/cars")
  public List<Cars> getPersonCars(@PathParam("id") long personId) {
    return carsResource.getPersonCars(personId);
  }
}


@Path("cars")
public class CarsResource {

  @GET
  @Path("all")
  public List<Car> getAllCars() {
    // ...
  }


  public List<Cars> getPersonCars(long personId) {
    Person person = findPersonById(personId);
    return person.getCars();
  }
}
```